# Writing nested schema to BigQuery from Dataflow (Python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Dataflow job to write to BigQuery. It works well for non-nested schema, however fails for the nested schema.

Here is my Dataflow pipeline:

```
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
  p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

  wordcount_options = pipeline_options.view_as(WordcountTemplatedOptions)

  schema = 'url: STRING,' \
           'ua: STRING,' \
           'method: STRING,' \
           'man: RECORD,' \
           'man.ip: RECORD,' \
           'man.ip.cc: STRING,' \
           'man.ip.city: STRING,' \
           'man.ip.as: INTEGER,' \
           'man.ip.country: STRING,' \
           'man.res: RECORD,' \
           'man.res.ip_dom: STRING'

  first = p | 'read' >> ReadFromText(wordcount_options.input)
  second = (first
            | 'process' >> (beam.ParDo(processFunction()))
            | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
              'myBucket:tableFolder.test_table',
              schema=schema)
  )
```

I created BigQuery Table using the following Schema is:

```
[
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "url",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "ua",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "method",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "man",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "fields":
      [
        {
          "mode": "REPEATED",
          "name": "ip",
          "type": "RECORD",
          "fields":
            [
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "cc",
                "type": "STRING"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "city",
                "type": "STRING"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "as",
                "type": "INTEGER"
              },
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "country",
                "type": "STRING"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
          "mode": "REPEATED",
          "name": "res",
          "type": "RECORD",
          "fields":
            [
              {
                "mode": "NULLABLE",
                "name": "ip_dom",
                "type": "STRING"
              }
            ]
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
BigQuery creation of import job for table "test_table" in dataset "tableFolder" in project "myBucket" failed., BigQuery execution failed., HTTP transport error:
 Message: Invalid value for: url is not a valid value
 HTTP Code: 400
```

**Question**
Can someone please guide me? What am I doing wrong?
Also, If there is a better way to iterate through all the nested schema and write to BigQuery please suggest?

**Additional info**
My data file:

```
{"url":"xyz.com","ua":"Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/63","method":"PUT","man":{"ip":{"cc":"IN","city":"delhi","as":274,"country":"States"},"res":{"ip_dom":"v1"}}}
{"url":"xyz.com","ua":"Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/63","method":"PUT","man":{"ip":{"cc":"DK","city":"munlan","as":4865,"country":"United"},"res":{"ip_dom":"v1"}}}
{"url":"xyz.com","ua":"Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/63","method":"GET","man":{"ip":{"cc":"BS","city":"sind","as":7655,"country":"India"},"res":{"ip_dom":"v1"}}}
```

Comment: First of all, why do you use WriteToBigQuery directly after ReadFromText? ReadFromText returns PCollection of strings, which are not compatible with input of WriteToBigQuery (it expects dictionaries)

Comment: Sorry @marcin-zablocki. I have a process function in between. Edited and added to my question. The process function returns a dictionary.

Comment: Does you dictionary contain proper data types? Do you parse the data properly? Seems like a trivial type error

Comment: It works for non-nested table. I just tried with two columns. I have added the data set with the process function. Can you guess what could be the error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you try to use **nested fields** while specifying *BigQuery Table Schema* **as string**, which is **not supported**. 
In order to push nested records into BigQuery from Apache Beam you need to create `TableSchema` object, i.e using built-in parser:

```
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import parse_table_schema_from_json
table_schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(your_bigquery_json_schema)
```

You need to pass schema as JSON string there, you can obtain it using the following command in your terminal (I assume that you have `gcloud tools` installed):

```
bq --project=your-gcp-project-name --format=json show your.table.name > schema.json
```

and in Python use it as follows:

```
table_schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(json.dumps(json.load(open("schema.json"))["schema"]))
```

Then in your pipeline:

```
 beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
              'myBucket:tableFolder.test_table',
              schema=table_schema)
```

You can also take a look at the example showing manual creation of `TableSchema` object:
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/474345f5987e47a22d063c7bfcb3638c85a57e64/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/bigquery_schema.py

which is (from the linked example):

```
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery
table_schema = bigquery.TableSchema()
full_name_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
full_name_schema.name = 'fullName'
full_name_schema.type = 'string'
full_name_schema.mode = 'required'
table_schema.fields.append(full_name_schema)

# A nested field
phone_number_schema = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
phone_number_schema.name = 'phoneNumber'
phone_number_schema.type = 'record'
phone_number_schema.mode = 'nullable'
number = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
number.name = 'number'
number.type = 'integer'
number.mode = 'nullable'
phone_number_schema.fields.append(number)

table_schema.fields.append(phone_number_schema)
area_code = bigquery.TableFieldSchema()
area_code.name = 'areaCode'
area_code.type = 'integer'
area_code.mode = 'nullable'
phone_number_schema.fields.append(area_code)
table_schema.fields.append(phone_number_schema)
```

then just use `table_schema` variable in `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery`.

Comment: Marcin, Do I need to pass `your_bigquery_json_schema ` as string? or just copy paste the json schema in their.
Like this -- `table_schema = parse_table_schema_from_json([{......}])` ?

Sorry I am slightly confused. Can you please add in your answer?

Comment: Thank you Marcin! I'll test this and update here. Currently, with the link you provided to create manual `TableSchema` object works. But I'll try using `parse_table_schema_from_json`.

Comment: This is great! It may overstate the need for JSON - you can just supply the schema as a nested python structure rather than JSON / using the parse function

Comment: Hi Maximillan, Can you please add it as an answer?

Comment: Mine schema has multiple nested layers. I got typeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. from parse_table_schema_from_json. Any suggestions?